# Not Able to Enable sa Account in SQL Server 2019 Express after Login with Windows Authentication Mode

Tags: sql-server, logins, windows-authentication, sa

I have installed SQL Server Express 2019 on my machine and after installation, I am able to login into server using the `Windows Authentication` method like

[image]

And as you can see the `sa` account has been disabled by default

[image]

So I tried to enable the `sa` account like

[image]

But I am getting this error message

[image]

> Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.(Microsoft SQL Server, Error:15151)

Even when I tried to change the server authentication mode from `Windows Authentication mode` to `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode` at

[image]

I am facing this error!

[image]

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_instance_regwrite', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error; 229)

So it looks like I have no/not granted any permission to do any anything! when login with Windows which apparently is my only option to get into server!(this is also happening when I tried to create new user!)

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can handle this to act as an administrator for DB when I login?

I have already seen and tried [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220586/cant-change-authentication-mode-from-windows-to-both-sql-server-and-windows), so please kindly, if you are not sure about the solution do not close, down vote or redirect me again to this post?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't have enough permissions to manage logins or anything else on the server.
You can verify this by running this command:

```sql
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin')
```

It should return 1 if you are a sysadmin, 0 otherwise.
If you are not a sysadmin, you need to make yourself an admin. Here is how you do it:

1. Stop the SQL Server service
2. Copy the path to the SQL Server executable from the service window. Open a cmd window (as admin) and run SQL Server interactively in single-user mode:

`<path to sql server executable>\sqlservr.exe" -m -s SQLEXPRESS`

3. Open another cmd window and run sqlcmd:
   `sqlcmd -S (local)\SQLEXPRESS`
4. Add yourself as sysadmin by running this command in sqlcmd:

```sql
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [DOMAIN\youruser]
GO
```

If it fails it means that you need to add your user explicitly in that sqlcmd window:

```sql
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\youruser] FROM WINDOWS;
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [DOMAIN\youruser];
GO
```

5. Press Ctrl+C on the cmd window where you have sql server running in single-user mode.
6. Start SQL Server process normally.

This should do.

Comment: You can use `net start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS /m` instead of running in the console.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-sql-server-in-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver16